# Python - Decorators - how to check function returning value (f(args))

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator, python-decorators

I want to check if returning value from the function is equal to 1, and if it is to return something else (for example True).
This is my code:

```
from functools import wraps
def decorator(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapping(*args,**kwargs):
        print (f(args))
        if f(args) == 1:
            return True
        return f(*args,**kwargs)
    return wrapping


@decorator
def f(x):
    return x

x=1
print(f(x))
```

and output:

```
(1,)
1
```

desired output is:

```
1
True
```

not sure how to achieve this.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not unpacking your arguments. When you use packed arguments with `*args, **kwargs` python takes what is passed into your function and assigns it to the variable args as a tuple. For example:

```
def f(*args):
    print(type(args))
    print(args[0])
    print(args[-1])

f(1, 2, 3)
```

will output

```
<class 'tuple'>
1
3
```

To get around this, you can unpack variables once they have been packed with `*`.
In your example:

```
from functools import wraps
def decorator(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapping(*args,**kwargs):
        print (f(*args))  # <----- notice we are now unpacking args into
                          # the function x, removing the wrapped tuple
        if f(*args) == 1:
            return True
        return f(*args,**kwargs)
    return wrapping


@decorator
def f(x):
    return x

x=1
print(f(x))
```

this should output the result you were expecting.

Answer (score 2):

Your code should be like this.

```
from functools import wraps


def decorator(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapping(*args, **kwargs):
        result = f(*args, **kwargs)
        if result == 1:
            return True
        return result
    return wrapping


@decorator
def f(x):
    return x


x = 1
print(f(x))
```

Here, the function is called once. The results are gotten and then compared.